# Edit > Improve dialog is poorly placed

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

When I try to `Edit > Improve` [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276917/sql-query-end-as-value-not-working-correctly), I get a modal dialog where I can't scroll to the bottom. Scrolling the inner scrollbar leaves the bottom of the modal window off-screen, and scrolling the outer scrollbar makes the modal dialog disappear (and I have to start over - there's a hole in the bucket).

Is this just happening to me? <strike>(Hopefully someone else can try to repro before the edit goes through.)</strike> To reproduce, someone with low enough rep, and a large enough screen I guess, will have to suggest an edit.

I have a fairly large screen (2560x1600) so I suspect either this problem is because of that (modal dialog sized / placed based on my screen) or that it is even worse for folks with smaller screens.

[image]

Comment: It doesn't like your **GINORMOUS** screen.  :)  I wish my screen was that big...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the real issue here is that clicking the scrollbar on the right dismisses the suggested edit popup.

Starting with the next build that will no longer be the case.